# Изменить цвет текста в ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Добавил данные в ListView, но цвет текста едва отличим от белого. Насколько я знаю, цвет текста в ListView по умолчанию черный. Пробовал добавить свойство цвета текста в simple_list_item_1, который использует ListView, но цвет текста не поменялся. В чем может быть причина?

[image: ListView с текстом серого цвета]

Comment: А можно xml показать Вашего simple_list_item_1 и ListView?

Comment: А лучше и код c "onCreate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать *свой собственный* макет элемента списка. Для этого нажмите правой кнопкой мышки по папке res/layout и выберите **New → Layout resounce file**. В открывшемся диалоговом окне укажите название файла (напр. `custom_listview_item`), а в Root element удалите `LinearLayout` и введите `TextView`. Далее откройте созданный файл и отредактируйте его: добавьте необходимые атрибуты для `TextView` (`id`, `layout_width`, `layout_height`, `textSize` и прочие), а также атрибут `textColor`, в значении которого вы укажете желаемый цвет (напр. черный `#000000`).

Скорее всего, вы не создавали свой собственный класс-адаптер, наследуемый от `BaseAdapter`, а воспользовались следующим вызовом:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Измените ресурс на свой собственный

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.custon_list_item, data);
```